# jquery scrollTo() in chrome disable mouse drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

im using jquery's 1.7.1 scrollTo()  to slide div containers horizontally when the user's clicks a button.
this works well except in Chrome, where the user can mouse drag between the containers. e.g when holding down the mouse button to select text in an input box (inside on of the containers) and then you keep holding it down while moving across the screen, this will scroll the containers. 
anyone have any ideas on how to stop this?

-example-
this isnt my site but has the same behaviour. [charliegentle.co.uk](http://charliegentle.co.uk) if you go to the contact page and hold down the mouse on one of the inputs and then drag slowly to the left

Answer (score 1):

If the containers don't need to be selectable you can use webkit specific CSS:

```
div {
    -webkit-user-select: ignore;
}
```

This should prevent the text inside the div elements from being selected when a user drags their mouse across them.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work as the drag can happen when selecting the text in a input box

Comment: Is the input box bigger than the scroll window then?

Comment: no.  but i can keep holding down the mouse and moving it passed the input box

Comment: Is the site live, can you supply a URL to it?

Comment: this isnt my site but has the same behaviour.  http://www.charliegentle.co.uk/
if you go to the contact page and hold down the mouse on one of the inputs and then drag slowly to the left

Comment: That has to be a bug, crazy! I'm guessing it's not checking for the selection bounds before scrolling. Especially as it only affects the single line text boxes! A workaround might be to display the inputs as single line text areas... not ideal though is it?!